# Jenkins not restoring NuGet packages with new MSBuild restore target

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild, nuget

We have a .net full framework WPF application that we've moved from **.net 4.6.2 to 4.7.1** along with changing to **PackageReference** in the csproj file instead of packages.config.

Building on the development machines appears to be fine and packages are downloaded and restored, but when we build on our **Windows Server 2012 build server with Jenkins**, the nuget packages don't seem to be restored correctly.

We're using **MSBuild v15.5** with the latest **"msbuild /restore"** command to restore packages at build time. 
Note: Using the previous way of calling "nuget restore" **does** work, but we should be able to use [msbuild /restore now](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/pull/2414).

The package restore process appears to be looking at the correct NuGet servers and appears to go through the restore without errors (this is a test solution compiled on Jenkins to isolate the issue):

```
Restore:
  Restoring packages for c:\Jenkins\workspace\Test\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj...
  Committing restore...
  Generating MSBuild file c:\Jenkins\workspace\Test\ConsoleApp1\obj\ConsoleApp1.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file c:\Jenkins\workspace\Test\ConsoleApp1\obj\ConsoleApp1.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Writing lock file to disk. Path: c:\Jenkins\workspace\Test\ConsoleApp1\obj\project.assets.json
  Restore completed in 577.05 ms for c:\Jenkins\workspace\Test\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj.

  NuGet Config files used:
      c:\Jenkins\workspace\Test\NuGet.Config
      C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config

  Feeds used:
      http://devbuild/NuGetHost/nuget
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Done Building Project "c:\Jenkins\workspace\Test\ConsoleApp1.sln" (Restore target(s)).
```

But when msbuild comes to compile the code we get the following errors which looks like the NuGet hasn't been downloaded:

```
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\log4net\2.0.8\lib\net45-full\log4net.dll' 
could not be found [c:\Jenkins\workspace\Test\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj]
```

Any idea why the nuget packages aren't getting restored?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

After many hours of searching and sifting through NuGet issue posts and filtering out the .net core noise, I have a fix!

According to some [NuGet](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6027) and msbuild [msbuild](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1830#issuecomment-285381121) issues raised, when restoring with NuGet (or msbuild /restore) 
under the local system account in Windows Server 2012, the folder NuGet uses isn't accessible or it's a different folder due to 32 bit vs 64 bit process that is running so it can't download nugets to that local cache folder.

This folder that msbuild wants to look in at compile time seems to be **C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages**.

The solve for us was to set the NuGet package cache folder using the System wide environment variable **NUGET_PACKAGES** to a different, accessible folder such as C:\NugetPackageCache
eg

```
NUGET_PACKAGES=C:\NugetPackageCache
```

You can also set this per Jenkins  project by setting the **Build Environment->Inject environment variables to the build process->Properties** Content to:

```
NUGET_PACKAGES=C:/NugetPackageCache
```

Another potential solve according to this [NuGet issue post](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6027#issuecomment-339417142) is to set the environment variable to the folder that msbuild is looking for the nugets ie

```
NUGET_PACKAGES=C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages
```

Note: The environment variables take precedence with NuGet. It doesn't look like they've updated the [NuGet docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#config-file-locations-and-uses) just yet to [mention the precedence](https://github.com/NuGet/learn.microsoft.com-nuget/issues/578).

**Note:** To inject/set the environment variables we are using the [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) Jenkins plugin which looks like this:

[image: Jenkins plugin with environment variables]

Comment: @mips please can you add a screen on how it will look like in Jenkins configuration. I have the same issue.

Comment: had the same problem with teamcity, this solution worked for me as well. thanks!

Comment: I've considered making the directory relative to the build directory, otherwise, you could end up with jobs sharing the directory, which might be ok, but makes jobs dependant of each other.

Comment: I had surrendered, till I found this post. I solved this by adding the following
`environment{
NUGET_PACKAGES="${env.WORKSPACE}/mynugetpackagecache"
}
`

Comment: I had an issue with a Jenkins installation. It was previously running under a domain user account and when I reinstalled, decided to install with LocalSystem. Added it as an Environment Variable on the system level, restarted Jenkins, and all was good.

Comment: Tried everything mentioned in the (other) answers and comments, but still doesn't help in my case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74145955/net-framework-project-4-5-2-fails-to-build-in-jenkins-due-to-missing-metadata-d

Answer (score 11):

For us it was indeed an issue with bitness!

The problem specifically is that MSBuild is actually looking for the nuget packages in the following directory:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages
```

Even though the logs actually say:

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages
```

Because the msbuild being called is a 32-bit process running on a 64-bit platform, when it looks in System32, it's actually looking into SysWOW64.

This is done by [file system redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector).

The solution for us was to simply call the 64-bit version of MSBuild, located at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
```

Notice the **amd64** in the path.

Answer (score 8):

We had a very similar but slightly different situation on a .NET Framework project, recently converted both to 4.7.2 and to use `<PackageReference>` rather than `packages.config`, building on Windows-based Jenkins servers where the service runs as Local System. In our case, we found that `nuget restore` was simply *not* looking at our private MyGet feed, and consequently wasn't installing our own packages from that source, which failed the build. It was not showing in the "feeds used" list following a `nuget restore` command.

Inspired by [mips](https://stackoverflow.com/users/625113/mips) answer here (and the NuGet issues linked to from there), I discovered that the issue was that, despite listing `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.config` as a configuration source (which was indeed where our MyGet feed was configured), in fact it was using `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.config` instead. I was able to solve the issue by copying the NuGet.config file from the system32 location to the SysWOW64 location.

There was no need to configure and inject a NUGET_PACKAGES environment variable.

Comment: Wow! That was exactly my problem the whole day with Jenkins and Nuget with package references. Evil that the system profile exists TWO times.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a different packages path in Nuget.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\NugetPackages" />
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="C:\NugetPackages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the below, assuming that TerminalHostBroker is the solution that contains some NuGet packages needing to be restored:

```
NuGet restore R:\Tools\TerminalHostBroker\TerminalHostBroker.sln -NonInteractive -NoCache -ConfigFile C:\Installers\NuGet.Config
```