# CS0006: CSC(0,0): Metadata file 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\..." could not be found

Tags: c#, batch-file, jenkins

Below are the set of commands I have written on the bat file to build my solution.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET msbuildPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
IF NOT EXIST %msbuildPath% SET msbuildPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
IF NOT EXIST %msbuildPath% SET msbuildPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
IF NOT EXIST %msbuildPath% SET msbuildPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
IF NOT EXIST %msbuildPath% SET msbuildPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
@ECHO on
%msbuildPath% %~dp0/../core-localization.sln /t:restore;build /p:Configuration=Release /v:m
set buildexitcode=%errorlevel%
@ECHO ...
@ECHO SCRIPT RUN: %~n0%~x0
@ECHO OFF
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a:%%b)
@ECHO ON
@ECHO DATE/ TIME: %mydate% %mytime%
@ECHO OFF
EXIT /B %errorlevel%
```

And I am trying to invoke this with help of PowerShell and Jenkins on an EC2 instance. 
below PowerShell code, I use on jenkins stage to execute:

```
"\$out = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { cmd.exe /c \"cd C:\\Bitbucket\\core-local\\tools\\ & resource_sync_build_release.bat\" *> c:\\buildlog.txt; return \$LASTEXITCODE }"
```

When I execute the same bat file locally on the instance it builds the solution successfully. However, when I am trying to run the same from Jenkins it exited with code 1 with below messages:

> C:\Bitbucket\core-local\tools>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" C:\Bitbucket\core-local\tools/../core-local.sln /t:restore;build /p:Configuration=Release /v:m
>
> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Framework
>
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Restore completed in 45.41 ms for C:\Bitbucket\core-local\src\resource\resource.csproj.
>
> CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.nuget\packages\xliff.om\1.0.2\lib\portable-net45+sl50+win+wpa81+wp80\Xliff.OM.dll' could not be found [C:\Bitbucket\core-local\src\resource\resource.csproj]
>
> CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.nuget\packages\yamldotnet\8.1.0\lib\net45\YamlDotNet.dll' could not be found [C:\Bitbucket\core-local\src\resource\resource.csproj]
>
> C:\Bitbucket\core-local\tools>set buildexitcode=1
>
> ...
>
> SCRIPT RUN: resource_sync_build_release.bat
>
> DATE/ TIME: 2020-05-27 10:28 AM

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48896486/jenkins-not-restoring-nuget-packages-with-new-msbuild-restore-target I believe that will resolve your issue